# SQL function question

Tags: sql

I have an sql function and at the end `RETURN @_result;`.

My question is that if I put this

```
REPLACE(@_result, '&', 'eseses')
REPLACE(@_result, '-', 'vagyvagy')
```

before `RETURN @_result;` that is OK?

`@_result` returns a long string and in that string I want to replace `&` to `eseses` and `-` to `vagyvagy`.

Comment: Think you need to specify your database manager software - Is this question about TransactSQL from SQLServer? You definitely need to retag this question to include the database type and development environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the following:

```
SET @_result = REPLACE(@_result, '&', 'eseses')
SET @_result = REPLACE(@_result, '-', 'vagyvagy')
```

Comment: Looks like we thought of the same thing at the same time. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the idea is ok but your code isn't syntactically sound. You'd need to do:

```
SET @_result = REPLACE(@_result, '&', 'eseses')
SET @_result = REPLACE(@_result, '-', 'vagyvagy')

RETURN @_result
```

You may know this but I wanted to ensure that you're clear on that in case you are trying it and it's not working. (Some DB implementations may allow REPLACE w/o the set, but I know of none.)

Answer (score 0):

yes that is okay in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You need the SET before the REPLACE in SQL 2008.

When I run the following

```
DECLARE @_result as varchar(30)

SET @_result = 'Hello-There & How are you?'

REPLACE(@_result, '&', 'eseses')
REPLACE(@_result, '-', 'vagyvagy')

SELECT @_result
```

I get the following error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'.
```

By updating it to the following, the error went away and everything is set correctly

```
DECLARE @_result as varchar(30)

SET @_result = 'Hello-There & How are you?'

SET @_result = REPLACE(@_result, '&', 'eseses')
SET @_result = REPLACE(@_result, '-', 'vagyvagy')

SELECT @_result
```